# How do I solve a "No PROJ.4 translation" error with gdal?

Tags: gdal, error, proj, gdalwarp

I've installed `gdal` using the `brew` utility on OS X so the `proj` and `geos` dependencies were also installed. I'm now trying to warp a GeoTIFF so that I can import it into Google Earth. I am getting a `proj` error, and cannot figure out how to solve it.

I use the following command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326" in.tif out.tif
```

and get the following error message:

```
Processing input file in.tif. 
ERROR 1: No PROJ.4 translation for source SRS, coordinate transformation initialization has failed.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

There is very little on Google about this error.

I have set my `GDAL_DATA` and `PROJ_LIB` environment variables to `/usr/local/shar/gdal` and `/usr/local/share/proj` respectively.

I do not think this is a problem with the input file since it appears to have a coordinate system defined already, checked with `gdalinfo`:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: in.tif
       in.tfw
Size is 341, 558
Coordinate System is:
LOCAL_CS["WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic",
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-3143782.158253818750381,3005869.481321755331010)
Pixel Size = (6268.758042377240599,-6268.758042377240599)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-3143782.158, 3005869.481) 
Lower Left  (-3143782.158, -492097.506) 
Upper Right (-1006135.666, 3005869.481) 
Lower Right (-1006135.666, -492097.506) 
Center      (-2074958.912, 1256885.987)
```

Comment: Can you make the source file available? Also, can you try explicitly setting the source SRS, since that doesn't look like a "full" / "known" coordinate system in the gdalinfo - it would normally have PROJCS[] at the start.

Comment: The image (and TFW file) is here: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/12453163/peninsula.zip. The suggestion to use EPS:3031 by @JayLaura worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your source coordinate system is most likely not defined in the CVS file that GDAL searches for proj4 strings.  It looks like you might be able to pass the source EPSG as 3031 (from [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3031/))

Note that it looks like your input is in a local projection.  Is this clipped from a larger raster?

To explicitly define the source you could just provide the proj4 string.  From the link above:

`gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs "EPSG:4326" in.tif out.tif`

Comment: Setting -s_srs 'EPSG:3031' solved it. Thank you. Any advice how I would have found 3031 from the missing 9001? I don't see a connection.

Comment: I just did a search on spatialreference.org for "Antarctic Polar Stereographic".